# Difference between Gateway and Interface VPC endpoints AWS

Tags: devops, roles

How can we use AWS VPC interface endpoints inside a vpc for a AWS service, like RDS ?

Isn't RDS inside a vpc already private traffic ?
For a AWS sercice not inside a vpc, this concept works fine, like Cloudwatch, SecretsManager etc.
I'm trying to understand for services which we can use inside a vpc how vpc Interface endpoint would be useful using AWS Private Link ?
Any clues ? Suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!!